# Find PDF of Z=X/(Y+c), c a constant and given independence of X and Y and the PDF of X and the PDF of Y

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

I want to find the PDF of $Z=X/(Y+c)$ where $c$ is a constant and $X,Y$ are two independent random variables. The PDFs of $X$ and $Y$ are supposed to be given.
I would like to have a general form using the PDFs of $X$ and $Y$. $X\geq 0$ and $Y\geq 0$

I thought of using the CDF but I cannot write it in terms of the PDF of $Y$.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 3):

You should use a two variable transform and then marginalize out the second variable. A good resource on this kind of technique is [the Casella and Berger book](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=en&lr=&id=FAUVEAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=casella+statistical+inference&ots=QxmDUk_7j9&sig=zyXT88BFRgrK56XuW9IFvT-I2Fg#v=onepage&q=casella%20statistical%20inference&f=false).

Use a two variable transform $\varphi$ as follows:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
U\\
V
\end{bmatrix}
= \varphi(X,Y) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
X\\
X/(Y+c)
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $\varphi$ is invertible and its inverse is
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
X\\
Y
\end{bmatrix}
= \varphi^{-1}(U,V) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\varphi^{-1}_1(U,V)\\
\varphi^{-1}_2(U,V)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
U\\
U/V - c
\end{bmatrix}$$
The joint PDF of $U,V$ is $p_{U,V}(u,v) = \lvert\det\mathrm{J}_{\varphi^{-1}}(u,v)\rvert p_{X,Y}(\varphi^{-1}_1(u,v), \varphi^{-1}_2(u,v))$.

I'll let you compute the jacobian $\mathrm{J}_{\varphi^{-1}}$ and its determinant. Then you can obtain the marginal $p_V$ by marginalisation:
$$p_V(v) = \int p_{U,V}(u,v)\,\mathrm{d}u$$